# Is this query any slower than if I declared a variable first?

Tags: .net, oracle

I'm sending queries to an Oracle database via C#/.NET and I found myself run into somewhat of a block when writing several of them. Here's one such example:

```
SELECT SOME_ID
FROM LOGS
WHERE
       AND (REPLACE_DTTM IS NULL 
            OR REPLACE_DTTM > TO_DATE(:VAR, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')) 
       AND INSTALL_DTTM < TO_DATE(:VAR, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM');
```

I frequently need to use this same bulky `TO_DATE(...)` nonsense to convert variables from C# to Oracle DATEs, but...

My question: Will this sort of query be particularly slow when the number of rows grows large? I have an index on `INSTALL_DTTM`, so I'm not particularly worried about that comparison -- I'm more concerned about the speed of the `TO_DATE` function and whether or not the query optimizer runs it multiple times for this query.

I've been avoiding declaring variables (e.g. `DECLARE var DATE := TO_DATE(...)`) because it's difficult to pass large queries with an OracleCommand object (I'd have to wrap the whole query in a couple `DECLARE...BEGIN...END` blocks) and essentially I'd be trying to fix a problem I'm not sure is even there. I'd like to know that there's a good reason for me to go out of my way to do so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My rule of thumb is to convert all variables to the correct type as soon as possible. In this case, convert them in C# before passing to Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about function calls like `TO_DATE` within the `WHERE` clause of your statement as they are only executed once per query and not for every row in the table or result.

Only for readability and clean code considerations this would be something to consider.